# Data type problem in sql export from sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got an export of a database made with SQL Developer, but unfortunately, the export that SQL Developer generated, contains data that should be of type NUMBER, but unfortunately are in the form: "10.3", so because of the quotation marks, they are interpreted as string, varchar by the Oracle database.

Given the huge amount of data that the export contains, I would like to be able to have a script, or a regular expression that detects each string in the file, which contains only numbers, decimals, but no text. And so replace its content by the number, or the decimal of the string, **but without the quotes this time**.

Here is the request to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "PERS". "TMP_MSG" 
   ("NAME" VARCHAR2(21 BYTE),
    "NUMERO" NUMBER(15,0),
    "IMP_NUMBER" NUMBER(15,0)
   ) SEGMENT IMMEDIATE CREATION 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 131072 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "PERS_DATA" ;
```

And here is the data insertion request:

```
Insert into PERS.TMP_MSG (NAME,NUMBER,IMP_NUMBER) values ('JEAN','2','-1');
```

Could someone help me to find a solution to avoid the **ORA-01722 invalid number error**.

Comment: What is the format of source file? Is it a CSV? You may set [NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS.html) for your session and import number-like strings with implicit type conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @astentx, I did think about NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS but unfortunately it seems to me that it only concerns commas, and periods for decimal numbers, so it's only separators. But here, it's quotation marks around the numbers, so I don't think that's what it's for.

Otherwise, the file format is .sql

Comment: The export was done from a system where those numbers were stored as strings, that's the only reason SQLDev would exported them as quoted. Oracle can easily take a string of '-2' and know that's actually -2.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that Oracle can interpret a number surrounded by quotation marks as a number.
But what I don't understand is that the SQL Developer database copy tool is able to create the table in my database and insert the associated data. Only the export tool does not do anything.
So at this point, I would have liked to access the final query of the database copy tool to take a look at it, but it is unfortunately impossible :(

Comment: If only I could make it insert the lines, ignoring the fact that they are strings. That would have allowed me to see, if my program behind still works.

Comment: As strange it may sound but "alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,' ;" makes that "select /*insert*/ * from some_table;" makes that numeric values will not be quoted in the generated "insert ..." statement.

Comment: @astentx as solved my problem with NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS. Thanks you :)

Comment: @p3consulting as solved my problem with NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS. Thanks you :)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't mark the comments as having solved my problem, there is no button that allows me to do so.
If anyone knows how to do it, I'm interested :)